# How to show dialog box without context in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dialog

I was trying to use the firebase cloud assessing and in the process, I want to just show a popup dialogue to the user on the arrival of the push notification. But to show the dialogue we need thee context object as one of the arguments of `showDialog` is `BuildContext`.

I tried many approaches but that didn't work. As of now, my code looks likes this:

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
          print('onMessage: $message');
          return;
        },
        onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
          print('onResume: $message');
          return;
        },
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
          print('onLaunch: $message');
            Text('onLaunch: $message'),
          );
          return;
        });
```

**Note:** This code is written in a separate class, and I am trying to achieve it without any 3rd part library.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't show a dialog without a valid context. 
Why don't you simply pass a `BuildContext` to your class like this?

```
class SeparateClass {
  final BuildContext context;

  SeparateClass(this.context);

  void configure() {
    // your rest of the configuration code
    // you can use showDialog(context, ...) here
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this too, it's not working for me. I called this config method of `NotificationManager` from the build method of main.dart by passing BuildContext object. Still, it's not showing the popup.

Comment: @DKAnsh Please post your full code, if it is reproducible I can assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

i solved a similar problem that shows a SnackBar instead a Dialog. With this code you can launch a SnackBar or Dialog wherever you want in your application.

```
import 'package:collectio/pages/init_screen_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'helper.dart';

void main() {
  Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType = null;
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
      // here the context refers to MaterialApp widget,
      // you can´t call Scaffold.of(context)
        body: Builder(builder: (context) {
          // here the context refers to Scaffold widget
          Helper.startFirebaseMessaging(context);
          return InitScreenPage();
        }),
    ));
  }
}

class Helper {
  static startFirebaseMessaging(BuildContext buildContext) {
    final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        var notification = message['notification'];

        // build the snackbar
        final snackBar = SnackBar(
          content: Text(notification['title']),
          action: SnackBarAction(
              label: 'Ok',
              onPressed: (){}
          ),
        );

        try {
          Scaffold.of(buildContext).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(
            sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
      print("Push Messaging token: $token");;
    });
    print("Waiting for token...");
  }
}
```

Maybe you can apply this to your code.